# Show counter of repeated content in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array loop:

**Array Function:**

```
$truckTypesArray = array( 

                            "1" => "03 m3",
                            "2" => "05 m3",
                            "3" => "08 m3",
                            "4" => "10 m3",
                            "5" => "12 m3",
                            "6" => "14 m3",
                            "7" => "20 m3",
                            "8" => "20 m3 Hayon",

                            );


function getTruckTypes($truckTypesArray, $id)
{
    return $truckTypesArray[$id];
}
```

**Loop Code:**

```
while($fetchPresentTruckTypes = mysql_fetch_array($getTruckTypeQuery))
{
    $createTruckTypeArray[]   = getTruckTypes($truckTypesArray, $fetchPresentTruckTypes['truckTypeId']);                    

}

$allTructTypes  = implode(",",$createTruckTypeArray);
```

Right now it generating this output which is fine:

```
20 m3, 03 m3, 20 m3, 10 m3, 20 m3,
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
20 m3 = 3,
03 m3 = 1,
10 m3 = 1
```

Comment: Try with array_count_values()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). It counts your array for you and returns what you need.

Comment: Well, no, but the example on PHP.net is pretty straightforward and will give you the usage. Something like `$models = array_count_values($all_the_trucks);` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
function createTruck($createTruckTypeArray){
  $result = array();
  foreach($createTruckTypeArray as $val){
     $result[$val] = array_count_values($val);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

This function return an array like this

```
array(
  '20 m3' => 3,
  '03 m3' => 1,
  '10 m3' => 1 
);
```

This can implode your result. Not try so please check

```
implode(', ', array_map(function ($v, $k) { return $k . '=' . $v; }, $result, array_keys($result)));
```